# Rasterise heights from a 3D linestring

Tags: raster, 3d, linestring, rasterization

I have a 3D network of streams represented using linestrings with Z-coordinates. I would like to rasterise this feature, where the raster values represent the linearly interpolated Z-values between 3D coordinates from the linestring verticies. I have all open source and Esri tools available, but I don't see any simple solution.

Did I miss an available tool to do this conversion, or do I need to make one myself? (I have a few ideas floating around my head, but it would probably take the better part of an afternoon to code out.)

Comment: It would be nice to know this answer. I used to convert polyline to evenly spaced points and than to raster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not tried it, but GDAL's [gdal_rasterize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html) should do the trick with its `-3d` option:

```
gdal_rasterize -3d -tr 10.0 10.0 -l streams streams.shp streams.tif
```

Comment: This is a really excellent tool! It also [has an API "GDALRasterizeLayers"](http://www.gdal.org/gdal__alg_8h.html#adfe5e5d287d6c184aab03acbfa567cb1) with intriguing options; for Python, see `help(gdal.RasterizeLayer)`

Comment: Could pose as a new question, but what if you had multiple Z values within a linestring? Such as starting coord z=1 and ending coord z=2? Doesn't seem like gdal_rasterize works for that.