# Rasterise 3D polyline using z-values to interpolate cell values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, interpolation, 3d-analyst, rasterization

Using ArcMap 10.5.1.
I have a ZM polyline composed of 3x vertices, with the vertex z-values representing water level at wells.  I am looking for a tool to rasterize this polyline, using the z-values to linearly interpolate the raster cell values between the wells (the ultimate aim is to then use these values with the Euclidian Allocation tool and other inputs to calculate the water table level).

I am aware that such a facility exists in GDAL (see: [Rasterise heights from a 3D linestring](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28216/rasterise-heights-from-a-3d-linestring)) but I cannot find an ArcGIS tool to do the same. The examples I can find (e.g. Interpolate Shape) are for adding z-values to a 2D polyline from an existing raster.

Comment: Consider create TIN

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to an Advanced license, you could:

1. convert polyline's vertices to points with [Feature Vertices To Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-vertices-to-points.htm)
2. open the Attribute table of the point feature created in step 1, add a new field called something like "Z_coord" and Calculate Geometry choosing "Z coordinates"
3. use the [Point to Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/point-to-raster.htm) choosing the field created in step 2 as `value_field` parameter

I am just not quite sure that the first function (Feature Vertices To Points) would retain the Z information, but I guess so.

Comment: That tool honours the [Output has Z value](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/environments/output-has-z-values.htm) environment setting, so as long as they have set that to _Enabled_ that tool should pass over any Z values in the vertices.

Comment: Great information, thanks!